# dynamic object creation via url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, javascript-objects

Trying to create a new instance of a mongoose model dynamically via a url request uisng express.

In the below example if const kind = 'modelOne' via the url I get 'Cannot read property 'modelOne' of undefined. Must be something up here but I cant figure it out.

```
const { modelOne } = require('./modelOne');
const { modelTwo } = require('./modelTwo');
const { modelThree } = require('./modelThree');

function response(req, res) {
 const kind = req.body.kind;
 const object = new this[kind] ({
  text: req.body
 });
};
```

Comment: Since you're already using destructuring, you should do `const { kind } = req.body;`. What is the scope of `this` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I wouldn't recommend you doing it this way even if it could work. It's always better not to trust the data you're getting in your requests. Try rather `switch` or sth like this:

```
const { modelOne } = require('./modelOne');
const { modelTwo } = require('./modelTwo');
const { modelThree } = require('./modelThree');
const models = {modelOne, modelTwo, modelThree}

function response(req, res) {
 const kind = req.body.kind;
 const object = new models[kind] ({
  text: req.body
 });
};
```

The object referenced by `this` doesn't contain all the imported modules. I guess you're using Express so `this === global`. Try putting `console.log(this)` to the function and you'll see what all fields it contains.

Comment: Thanks Jan Steuer this does work. I am a newb to this as you might tell. The reason I am structuirng this way is to avoid creating a seperate POST route for each model. BUT are you saying this is preferencial and I should be creating seperate POST routes for each model as opposed to doing it dynamically as above and relying on the data coming in through the url request?